# Unwanted page breaks in Jasper iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using one master reports with some static data and three subreports. Subreports can repeat zero to many times and are approximately half page long. I have put each subreport in a separate table and each such table on a separate detail band.

My problem is that each subreport always starts on a new page. They each consist of multiple detail bands that all have "Split allowed" set to true

Comment: If you can post the relevant parts of the JRXML, that should help people figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "When No Data - No Pages" property may do what you want.